# why is the json returning null values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a javascript function that calls a method in the code behind for an asp.net c# application. I pass an array into JSON.stringify which returns the string equivalent to the jsonText value below. The values below represent only one of the records returned.

```
var jsonText = "[{\"eacItem\":{\"ID\":\"dc97d510-cd29-4a23-af7f-36c0acfa1914\",\"AP\":\"201407\",\"EAC\":\"0\"}}]";
```

The string is then passed into the function to call the method in the code behind.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true, //might be needed for serialization to work properly
            url: pagePath + "/" + "TestMethod",
            data: "{'eacArray':" + jsonText + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("successfully posted data");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed posted data");
                alert(postData);
            }

        });
```

This is the method in the code behind that is called.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void TestMethod(List<eacItem> eacArray)
{
  //do something
}
```

This is the Class associated with the JSON data set as the parameter type for the method.

```
public class eacItem
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string AP { get; set; }
   public string EAC { get; set; }

}
```

The data passed into the method contains the record(s) but the values are all null as shown in the screenshot below. I am not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any help.

[image: null array]

[image: in code behind]

Additional info that was requested. Here is a screenshot of the value in eacArray.
[image: eacArray]

This is  the JSON string in debug
[image: JSON]

Result of JSON.stringify(eacArray) in 
data: "{'eacArray':" + JSON.stringify(eacArray) + "}",

"[{\"eacItem\":{\"AP\":\"201407\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"dc97d510-cd29-4a23-af7f-36c0acfa1914\"}},{\"eacItem\":{\"AP\":\"201304\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"69326e1b-8d69-431f-8a5b-29f8b279d74c\"}},{\"eacItem\":{\"AP\":\"201305\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"69326e1b-8d69-431f-8a5b-29f8b279d74c\"}},{\"eacItem\":{\"AP\":\"201306\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"69326e1b-8d69-431f-8a5b-29f8b279d74c\"}}]"

**Here is the corrected code in case it can help anyone:**

```
         //Iterate through elements on page
         $('ElementContainingValue').each(function () {
            var ap = this.attributes.ap.value;
            var id = this.attributes.id.value;
            var eac = $(this).val();
            var eacItem = { "AP": ap, "EAC": eac, "ID": id };
            eacArray.push(eacItem);

        });

        var pagePath = window.location.pathname;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true, //might be needed for serialization to work properly
            url: pagePath + "/" + "TestMethod",
            data: "{'eacArray':" + JSON.stringify(eacArray) + "}",
            // Contents of eacArray after stringify
            // "[{\"AP\":\"201407\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"dc97d510"},{\"AP\":\"201408\",\"EAC\":\"0\",\"ID\":\"dc97d510-cd29-4a23-af7f-36c0acfa1914\"}]
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("successfully posted data");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed posted data");
                alert(postData);
            }
        });
```

This is the method called in the code behind.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void TestMethod(List<eacItem> eacArray)
    {
        foreach (var eacItem in eacArray)
        {
            string ap = eacItem.AP;
            string id = eacItem.ID;
            string eac = eacItem.EAC;
        }
    }
```

This is the class associated with the array.

```
  public class eacItem
  {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string AP { get; set; }
    public string EAC { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: Do you control the JSON output... that is, the JSON that you're submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M.Babcock definitely has you on the right track I think. I have not worked in .NET land hardly at all, so I could be off on this, but your testMethod seems to be expecting a List type, and actually what you are passing in that stringified JSON looks more like a Map. Perhaps you need to change your JSON to look more like this?

```
var jsonText = "[{\"ID\":\"dc97d510-cd29-4a23-af7f-36c0acfa1914\",\"AP\":\"201407\",\"EAC\":\"0\"}, {\"ID\":\"anotherId\",\"AP\":\"anotherAP\",\"EAC\":\"etc\"}]";
```

And then you'd be in business?

Comment: This is what I needed. I had seen examples that specified to add the class, in this case eacItem, to each item in the array. Removing that gave the desired result. I have added the corrected code to the end of the original post.Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome @JDM! I'm happy to have helped, but I would kindly ask that you accept this answer so that future readers of this question better understand the mistake and how to avoid it :) Glad you're up and running!

Answer (score 3):

Your POST data is: `{'eacArray':" + jsonText + "}"` which doesn't contain any information that would be mappable to `eacItem` (no matching properties, etc).

Verify that you're passing the result of `JSON.stringify` in the request (possibly using Fiddler or Wireshark). You need to ensure that the data you expect to go over the wire matches what you expect to be sent.

Comment: In the string for jsonText I have ID, AP, and EAC. Shouldn't these match up with the properties in the class eacItem?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't look like that is what you're passing to `$.ajax`.

Comment: Please see the edit at the end of my original post for the detail you requested. thanks

Comment: Fiddler is reporting d = null but I am not sure why that is since the debug is showing values being passed in.

Comment: I see your updates from (what appears to be VS) if you have others then they aren't working.

Comment: added result from stringify to original post

Comment: The data was there but I was getting thrown off by the additional "eacItem": I was placing at the front of each item in the array.See the end of the original post for the complete corrected code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove contentType attribute to make it work

Comment: Are you sure that'll work for the OP? I thought the `contentType` was what the only way the framework used to know how to process the request?

Comment: Otherwise the browser does not send anything to server

Comment: Why would that be? You have to have some way of telling `$.ajax` the format of the request so it knows how to set the `ContentType` header. Removing it would likely break the .NET side of the communication (it'll assume it is XML). Is there a more appropriate JQuery alternative?

Comment: commenting out the contentType causes the function to fail.